# Why does a canvas break flex sizing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-canvas

I have a trivial flex layout here. The two vertical columns are the same size. Uncommenting the canvas element breaks the symmetry even when the width of the canvas is smaller than the width of its containing div.

Why, and how do I fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="/assets/live.js"></script>
      <style>
         * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         html, body {
            height: 100%;
         }
         body {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: blue;
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: flex;
         }
         div {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            border: 1px solid green;
         }
         canvas {
            border: 1px solid purple;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div></div>
      <div>
         <!-- <canvas></canvas> -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `flex: 1 1 auto;` --> `flex: 1 1 0;` if you want *always* equal size

Comment: and min-width:0 to div for small screens

Comment: That fixes it. I hadn't understood how flex-basis affects the outcome. Can you post it as an answer and I'll accept it plz.

Comment: I already gave a duplicate detailing this